# Start a program with a macro in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I would like to start a program in Excel with a macro -

In Windows, I am doing this with the following macro-script, and it works fine:

```
Sub generate()
    Dim FN As String
    FN = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
    FN = FN + "\pricingCalc.exe"
    Shell FN, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Now I tried to bring this also on macOS to running - (I simply choose the name of the executable program on macOS without an .exe)

```
Sub generate()
    Dim FN As String
    FN = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
    FN = FN + "\pricingCalc"
    Shell FN, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

But when I try to click the associated button in Excel (or start the macro manually in the VB-editor) nothing happens... (when I do the same on Windows the program opens as expected - but nothing happens on macOS - no program / no error message or something)

(I also tried to change the "" to an "/" - but in that case I get an error message that the program is not found)

UPDATE - added also 2 pics where you can see the path in the finder and the error in the macro -

Here you can see the file and the path of the file at the bottom:
[image]

And here you can see using the same path and the error in the vb-macro in excel:
[image]

Comment: Try using `&` instead of `+`.  You can't add text.

Comment: Tried it with
Sub generate()
    Dim FN As String
    FN = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
    FN = FN & "\pricingCalc"
    Shell FN, vbNormalFocus
End Sub

But unfortunately still nothings happens

Comment: btw - is the "\" correct or shoudn´t it be a "/" on MacOS?
(i have tried to change it to "/" but with that i get an error that he didn´t find the file - when i am using "\" it does nothing)

Comment: Have you got a MacOS version of pricingCalc.exe on that machine?  You cannot expect a random .exe made for Windows to run on Mac or any other OS without modification. Unix-based OS's like MacOS use forward slashes to denote subdirectories - when you converted to them and the Shell command told you the .exe was not there then probably it was not.

Comment: Yes of course this is a running executable on MacOS - when i am starting it from the finder everything works fine.

Comment: Maybe it had something to do with the path. How can i check if the full path of the program is working in the finder/ Macos?